# Bash Script Loops Back Instead of Exiting

Tags: bash, scripting

I have written a Bash installation script to help people to install a mod I made for a game called [Minetest](http://minetest.net). The script executes successfully and copies the current folder to `.../minetest_game/mods`.

However, I have set up another option to allow users to change the subgame (folder) in which the mod is installed by running `./install.sh other_subgame`. This runs successfully and installs the mod in the correct folder. However, instead of exiting at the end of the script, I am brought back to a previous function called `subStall`. Note that when I simply run `./install`, this does not happen.

When the `substall` function is run again at the end, the user could just use `Ctrl+C` and exit, but it is still of annoyance and might confuse some users.

Any ideas? If you would like to see my full script, you can view it [here](http://67.201.165.88:3000/endev15/server_tools/src/master/install.sh). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off a debugging suggestion. When you don't know what a script is doing add `set -x` to it. Then the shell will print out each command that runs before it runs it. (There are other things you can do and fancier ways to debug with more precision but that's a good first step.) Having done that likely would have let you follow the flow of your program to see what was going on.

Second, please try to include *in the post* an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for your problem (or at least a pastebin or gist or other git repo). Making people download a file is generally frowned upon and makes it much less likely that people will actually spend the time looking into your problem.

That said you don't need to do that to follow the flow and see what was happening (assuming I followed it correctly that is).

It looks like the problem is that on line `145` you check if `$subgame` was passed to the script and if it has been then you immediately call `midCheck` (line `149` and `midCheck` eventually calls `install`). After that you keep going in the `subStall` function and eventually hit line `162` which calls `midCheck` *again*.

I assume that's what you are seeing. Fixing that (by exiting after calling `midCheck` in the `if` statement or better by only checking for `$subgame` and running lines `152-159` only if it isn't set and then only calling `midCheck` in one place) should solve the problem.

As additional comments. Avoiding calling the same function in multiple places (for various `if` conditions) is probably a good idea. You may also want to run your script through http://www.shellcheck.net/ to see what common issues it catches (such as unused variables and the like).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by adjusting my if statement so that instead of setting `null=""` upon finding that no input had been previously given, it would run a new function called `subQuery`. This fixed my problem, and the script now runs properly.

From my basic understanding, I think that to simplify things, having an if statement which runs then do nothing, is a bad idea. If you need an if statement that continues when it receives certain data, but does something else if other data is received, do not do it by basically leaving the then statement blank. Make a function in which the next part of the script is stored, and link to it through the if statement.

Thanks for the help. And if I haven't made something clear enough, please let me know. I am not used to this stuff yet.